# Get filename and line number that called vim autoload function

Tags: vim, trace, autoload

I'm trying to populate the quickfix list using an autoload function, i.e.:

```
function! myplugin#myfunc(msg)

  " this doesn't work from *inside* an autoload function
  let filename = fnamemodify(resolve(expand('<sfile>:p')))

  " not sure if it's possible to get the line number from where
  " a function was called
  let linenum = '?#'

  " create qf dict object
  " set filename, line number, bufnr, text, etc
  " add dict to qflist
  " setqflist(qfdictlist)
endfunction!
```

The problem I've run into is I can't figure out a way to get the filename and line number from the code that *called* the autoload function. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is an autoload function?

Comment: ok, you meant autoload script.... I thought you are looking for some function to auto load some file when some event triggered...

Comment: are you looking for `expand("<lnum>")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box. This is not possible.

However, depending on the exact scenario, here are a few leads.

- I've attempted to write a function that decodes the callstack from `v:throwpoint` when an exception is caught. It's still experimental. See https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/exception.vim
- From my [test unit framework](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-UT), I know precisely which test-file/line is failing. To do so, I had to parse the UT file in order to inject the line number of the caller into the `:Assert*` commands.

As you see, none of these solutions is very good. But there are none other right now. The callstack isn't available, except from `v:throwpoint` in an exception context. The only other solution is to have callers inject their references (~`__FILE__` + ~`__LINE__`) when calling. And the only way to automate this is to *compile* the caller script into another script that automatically injects the missing information.

By *right now*, understand there had been a proposal on vim-dev mailing list this last month in order to permit to have access to the call stack, but alas, only during debugging sessions: https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/433
If this is accepted, may be it could be extended later to offer a viml function that'll export this information.

---

EDIT: Your question inspired me to write a [simplistic logging facility](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Log.md) for vim:

```
" Function: lh#log#new(where, kind) {{{3
" - where: "vert"/""/...
" - kind:  "qf"/"loc" for loclist
" NOTE: In order to obtain the name of the calling function, an exception is
" thrown and the backtrace is analysed.
" In order to work, this trick requires:
" - a reasonable callstack size (past a point, vim shortens the names returned
"   by v:throwpoint
" - named functions ; i.e. functions defined on dictionaries (and not attached
"   to them) will have their names mangled (actually it'll be a number) and
"   lh#exception#callstack() won't be able to decode them.
"   i.e.
"      function s:foo() dict abort
"         logger.log("here I am");
"      endfunction
"      let dict.foo = function('s:foo')
"   will work correctly fill the quicklist/loclist, but
"      function dict.foo() abort
"         logger.log("here I am");
"      endfunction
"   won't
" TODO: add verbose levels
function! lh#log#new(where, kind) abort
  let log = { 'winnr': bufwinnr('%'), 'kind': a:kind, 'where': a:where}

  " open loc/qf window {{{4
  function! s:open() abort dict
    try
      let buf = bufnr('%')
      exe 'silent! '.(self.where). ' '.(self.kind == 'loc' ? 'l' : 'c').'open'
    finally
      call lh#buffer#find(buf)
    endtry
  endfunction

  " add {{{4
  function! s:add_loc(msg) abort dict
    call setloclist(self.winnr, [a:msg], 'a')
  endfunction
  function! s:add_qf(msg) abort dict
    call setqflist([a:msg], 'a')
  endfunction

  " clear {{{4
  function! s:clear_loc() abort dict
    call setloclist(self.winnr, [])
  endfunction
  function! s:clear_qf() abort dict
    call setqflist([])
  endfunction

  " log {{{4
  function! s:log(msg) abort dict
    let data = { 'text': a:msg }
    try
      throw "dummy"
    catch /.*/
      let bt = lh#exception#callstack(v:throwpoint)
      if len(bt) > 1
        let data.filename = bt[1].script
        let data.lnum     = bt[1].pos
      endif
    endtry
    call self._add(data)
  endfunction

  " reset {{{4
  function! s:reset() dict abort
    call self.clear()
    call self.open()
    return self
  endfunction

  " register methods {{{4
  let log.open  = function('s:open')
  let log._add  = function('s:add_'.a:kind)
  let log.clear = function('s:clear_'.a:kind)
  let log.log   = function('s:log')
  let log.reset = function('s:reset')

  " open the window {{{4
  call log.reset()
  return log
endfunction
```

Which use this other function of mine that decodes the callstack.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. Unfortunate it's not possible. :(

Comment: May be, you could in your log function throw an exception that you catch immediately. From there you fetch the v:throwpoint variable and decode the penultimate function and apply offsets from function start. This may slow down your library functions drastically. And yes indeed, this is an awful workaround.

Comment: It just occurred to me that it might be a valid approach to setup commands which collect the filename and line number from where they are called and pass them into the functions. I'm working atm, so haven't had a chance to play with this yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can't get the file and line from *inside* the autoload function, you have to pass that *into* your function.

Your autoloaded function is invoked somehow, either by a custom mapping, command, or on an `:autocmd` event. From *there*, you can resolve the current file (`expand('%')` and line number (`'line('.')`) and pass that in.

But *why* do you need that?! For normal editing tasks, I can't imagine why. If you're writting a custom Vim debugging plugin, okay, that might be useful. But debugging via Vimscript is difficult (as you've found out), the callstack isn't exposed. Better stick with the built-in `:debug` and `:breakadd`; I've so far found them sufficient.

Comment: I've been banging away at a 'logging' plugin as a learning exercise - and because I thought it would be something that *might* be interesting and/or potentially useful (at least for me). Write now I populate a buffer with an array, but realized it would be better to leverage quickfix and be able to jump straight to where the message was generated from.